# Combining flash files

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

So, I'm naturally a PHP coder, but I have to use flash for a part of a project.

I was wondering if I have files such as mainsite.swf and page1content.swf, is there a way to simply include the page1content.swf file into a predefined area on the mainsite.swf file (as in PHP's include)?

Also, would it be possible to use this flash "include" to embed external swf's?

Finally, ideally I'd be able to merge these files together, but from what I've read, it's a tricky business, with filenames, referencing etc, so this is optional.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I'll be using actionscript 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to load an external swf into a movie clip on the stage.

Have a look at this - http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html#main_Using_the_ActionScript_2_0_loadMovie_command

I'm not sure what you mean by merging the movies, what exactly do you need them to do?

Comment: Thanks, this seems pretty much what I wanted, I was just wondering if there was a way of doing it without movieclips etc, just a single line of code on the main frame, that embedded the external swf.